# Does Realm supports fuzzy query On Android

Tags: android, database, realm, realm-mobile-platform

My team decides to use realm as databases,But I have a question to ask,
Does Realm supports fuzzy query like SQLite use keyword 'like' or '%' .Sometimes we need to use fuzzy query

Comment: Like query is supported since 2.3.0 see  https://github.com/realm/realm-java/issues/3752

Answer (score 5):

[LIKE query is supported since 2.3.0.](https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/api/io/realm/RealmQuery.html#like-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-)

```
public RealmQuery<E> like(String fieldName,
                          String value,
                          Case casing)

Condition that the value of field matches with the specified substring, with wildcards:
    '*' matches [0, n] unicode chars
    '?' matches a single unicode char.

Parameters:
    fieldName - the field to compare.
    value - the wildcard string.
    casing - how to handle casing. Setting this to Case.INSENSITIVE only works for Latin-1 characters.
```

Examples:

```
realm.where(Person.class).like("name", "*").findAll();
realm.where(Person.class).like("name", "?ohn*", Case.SENSITIVE).findAll();
```